# Cyclic quadrilaterals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Given a cyclic quadrailateral $ABCD$ such that $AB=BC=7$  Let M be the point of intersection of the 2 diagonals. If $DM=5$ Find $BM$.

For a quadrailateral to be cyclic that means the sum of opposite sides must be equal to the sum of opposite sides that is, $A+C=B+D$ but $7+D=7+C$ implies that $D=C$ so it could be any number like $1,2,3...$ How am I suppose to use this relationship to find $BM$?

Comment: The normal definition of a cyclic quadrilateral is one whose vertices lie on a circle; this happens if opposite angles sum to $180^{\circ}$. Are you sure the definition above is the one you want to use? (It is *not* equivalent).

Comment: Ahhh okok I get you thanks